# single virtual inheritance compiler optimization in c++?

Tags: c++, performance, inheritance, dependency-injection, vtable

If I have this situation in C++ project:

- 1 base class 'Base' containing only pure virtual functions
- 1 class 'Derived', which is the only class which inherits (public) from 'Base'

Will the compiler generate a VTABLE?

It seems there would be no need because the project only contains 1 class to which a Base* pointer could possibly point (Derived), so this could be resolved compile time for all cases.

This is interesting if you want to do dependency injection for unit testing but don't want to incur the VTABLE lookup costs in production code.

Comment: The compiler won't know it the base class will be inherited in another source file or not, so it will probably add a vtable anyway.

Comment: Ow, right, could have thought of that, your answer seems likely to be the right one. So it seems I will not be using a pointer to a virtual base class to register dependencies, but give my test classes the same names as the production dependencies and conditional compile my test classes in (and my production classes out) for the unit tests...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a VTABLE required when the derived class doesn't override the virtual function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109662/why-is-a-vtable-required-when-the-derived-class-doesnt-override-the-virtual-fun)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have hard data, but I have good reasons to say no, it won't turn virtual calls into static ones.

- Usually, the compiler only sees a single compilation unit. It *cannot know* there's only a single subclass, because five months later you may write another subclass, compile it, get some ancient object files from the backup and link them all together.
- While link-time optimizations do see the whole picture, they usually work on a far lower-level representation of the program. Such representation allow e.g. inlining of static calls, but don't represent inheritance information (except perhaps as *optional* metadata) and already have the virtual calls and vtables spelt out explicitly. I *know* this is the case for Clang and IIRC gcc's whole-program optimizations also work on some low-level IR (GIMPLE?).
- Also note that with dynamic loading, you can *still* add more subclasses long after compilation and LTO. You may not need it, but if I was a compiler writer, I'd be weary of adding an optimization that allows people royally breaking virtual calls in very specific, hard-to-track-down circumstances.
- It's rarely worth the trouble - if you don't need virtual calls (e.g. because you know you won't need any more subclasses), don't make stuff `virtual`. Review your design. If you need *some* polymorphism but not the full power of virtual, the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) may help.

Comment: Thanks, you triggered my into searching for a compile time polymorphic solution and someone already had something I think I can use: http://skepticalmethodologist.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/dependency-injection-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't have to use a vtable based implementation of virtual function dispatch at all so the answer to your question will be specific to the implementation that you are using.

Comment: I'm using gcc, this has a list of optimization options: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html. But I can't really find one that seems to apply. The point is that 'maybe' isn't really acceptable.

Comment: @Sjimmie: my guess is that it won't optimize it. have you checked the compiled code?

Answer (score 0):

The vtable is usually not only used for virtual functions, but it is also used to identify the class type when you do some `dynamic_cast` or when the program accesses the `type_info` for the class.

If the compiler detects that no virtual functions ever need a dynamic dispatch and none of the other features are used, it just could remove the vtable pointer as an optimization.

Obviously the compiler writer hasn't found it worth the trouble of doing this. Probably because it wouldn't be used very often.